# How can I set attributes on a script tag in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In normal HTML or ERB, adding an attribute to a `<script>` tag is drop-dead simple, just like adding an attribute to anything else.  But in HAML you use the `:javascript` filter.  How can you add an attribute, such as `type="module"` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you can't set attributes on `:javascript` filter. However, you can combine `script` tag and `:plain` filter to get desired result, like this:

```
%script{type: "module"}
  :plain
    -# your JS code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an attribute inside the script tag.

ex:

```js
%script{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
```

Comment: HAML doesn't allow you to include JavaScript on the next line.  That's the purpose of the `:javascript` filter, to allow you to include a different language embedded in the HAML.  But the filter doesn't seem to allow attributes.

Answer (score -1):

In HAML, you can add attributes to a :javascript filter using the same syntax as for other elements. For example, to add the type="module" attribute to a :javascript filter, you can use the following syntax:

```
:javascript(type="module")
  // your JavaScript code here
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<script type="module">
  // your JavaScript code here
</script>
```

You can also add other attributes to the :javascript filter using the same syntax. For example, to add the defer attribute, you can use:

```
:javascript(type="module" defer)
  // your JavaScript code here
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<script type="module" defer>
  // your JavaScript code here
</script>
```

In addition to the type and defer attributes, you can use any other valid attribute for a script tag, such as src, async, integrity, and crossorigin. Just add them to the attribute list after the type and defer attributes, separated by spaces.

I hope this helps you add attributes to :javascript filters in HAML. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect: `:javascript(type="module")` gives `Invalid filter name ":javascript(type="module")"` as of haml 6.3.0.